# Qt Creator debugger shows nonsensical values for expression evaluator

Tags: c++, gdb, c++17, qt-creator

I have this simple qmake C++ project:
.pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++17
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O0 -ggdb3
target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/dev
INSTALLS += target
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using Seconds = std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<1, 1>>;

struct TimeSpan
{
    Seconds seconds;
};

TimeSpan operator + (TimeSpan left, TimeSpan right) { return { left.seconds + right.seconds }; }

int main()
{
    TimeSpan a = { Seconds(1) };
    TimeSpan b = { Seconds(2) };
    TimeSpan ab = a + b;
    auto as = a.seconds;
    auto bs = b.seconds;
    auto abs = as + bs;
    std::cout <<          a.seconds.count()
              << " + " << b.seconds.count()
              << " = " << ab.seconds.count()
              << " = " << (a + b).seconds.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<          as.count()
              << " + " << bs.count()
              << " = " << abs.count()
              << " = " << (as + bs).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program correctly prints

```
1 + 2 = 3 = 3
1 + 2 = 3 = 3
```

But when I put a breakpoint on `return 0;` and look at the expression evaluator, things go crazy:
[image]
The values for a, b, ab, as, bs and abs are correct (1 + 2 = 3). But for some reason it shows an insane value 1431658504 ((hex) 55556008) for adding `a + b` in the expression evaluator and it can't do `as + bs` at all. Interestingly, doing anything that refreshes the debugger (e.g. single step, modifying an evaluator, changing the display format, etc.) causes the value to change:
[image]
Now it shows -7352 ((hex) ffffffffffffe348). And now it's stuck at that value.

What's going on? The program is extremely simple. Is the debugger really tripping up on such a simple evaluation? What can I do to get it to behave correctly?

I'm using Qt Creator 5.0.2
The problem persists on multiple target architectures (x86 and ARM) but the wrong values are different.

Comment: `(a + b).seconds.count()` creates a temporary object, and that object is destroyed at the end of the full expression it is in.  Most likely you are just seeing what the value of that memory is, but you no longer own that memory so it's value no longer matters.

Comment: @NathanOliver That seems like a plausible explanation. Any way I can get the debugger to not do that, though?

Comment: Not do what?  Show you temporaries or destroy the temporaries?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not to show the garbage value after destroying the temporary object that it used to calculate the correct value.

Comment: Sorry, I do not.  I've not used QT Creator.  I do know that in MSVS their watch window has an option for locals and auto and IIRC auto would no show the temporary objects unless they were still in existance.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I put a breakpoint on `return 0;` and look at the expression evaluator, things go crazy

Question: do local variables get destructed *before*, *after*, or "in the middle" of that `return 0;` line?

You can find out by

1. disassembling `main` and
2. looking at the instruction pointer when the breakpoint is hit.

The fact that "things go crazy" suggests that the breakpoint is *after* the scope of `as` and `bs` has ended, and also after all local variables have been destructed ... in which case evaluating them yields undefined behavior (you are looking at random memory at that point, so the fact that the wrong values change between architectures is of little surprise).

This is somewhat expected: the debugger can't know your intention was to stop before the destructors.

You can either

- modify the source so you can stop *before* locals are destructed, or
- set the breakpoint on a "before destruction" address (which should be clear from disassembly).

Comment: I can put a breakpoint on an earlier line and the erroneous behavior still happens, so that's not it.